# How to match element from set according to user input?

Tags: python, pandas

All,

I have below dataframe, I am trying to find unique professions present in my "Job" column and based on user Input, I need to print output saying that "Client is eligible" else "Client is not Eligible". My below code Just goes to else statement. I am not sure what is Wrong. Any input is appreciated!

My Code so far....

```
df=pd.read_csv('bank-data.csv')
uniq_job_set=list(set(df['job'])) #Set of unique jobs
 prof=input('Enter Profession') #Input from user
 if prof==uniq_job_set:  
         print('Yes, Client is eligible')    
 else:
         print('No, Client is Not-eligible')
```

Dataframe used:

```
  age          job   marital    y
0   20      student    single  yes
1   32   management    single  yes
2   49   technician   married  yes
3   32  blue-collar   married  yes
4   33   management   married  yes
5   61       admin.   married  yes
6   45  blue-collar  divorced  yes
7   34   technician   married  yes
8   37   management   married  yes
9   27       admin.  divorced  yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `if` statement. You are comparing a list with a string, which will always be `False`. Use `if prof in uniq_job_set` instead:

```
uniq_job_set=list(set(df['job'])) 
prof=input('Enter Profession') 
if prof in uniq_job_set:  
    print('Yes, Client is eligible')    
else:
    print('No, Client is Not-eligible')
```